# Node.js - Global variable not found on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to implement socket.io-stream and in my server side file it works fine but on client side:

This is top part of clientside, this is where file stops loading, at ss.createStream() as "ss" is not found.

```
var socket = io.connect();
var username = null;
var userarray = null;
var stream = ss.createStream();
var filename="profile.jpg";

ss(socket).emit('profile-image', stream, {name: filename});
fs.createReadStream(filename).pipe(stream);
```

It always says ss is not defined even though I've added it in head of html.

 This is top of jade template, where the scripts are defined in head.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    script(src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js")
    script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js", type="text/javascript")
    script(src="script.js", type="text/javascript")
    script(src="http://chaterix.com/node_modules/socket.io-stream/socket.io-stream.js")
    script(src="char.js", type="text/javascript")
```

My structure is as follows:

```
root
-public
--script.js (client side)
-node_modules
--socket.io-stream
---socket.io-stream.js (the file I am trying to use)
server.js (server side)
```

I also tried using browsify as developer wrote:

```
$ npm install browserify -g
$ cd node_modules/socket.io-stream
$ browserify index.js -s ss > socket.io-stream.js
```

but that didn't help too.

socket.io-stream.js: 
https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream/blob/master/socket.io-stream.js

and here is top part of server.js (server side)

```
var http = require('http'),

    express = require('express'),

    app = express(),

    jade = require('jade'),

    server = http.createServer(app),

    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var io = require('socket.io');

var escape = require('escape-html');

io = io.listen(server);
var fs = require("fs");
var ss = require('socket.io-stream');
var path = require('path');
var Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities;

entities = new Entities();
server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Can you paste a little more of your code?  Its hard to figure out whats going on...

Comment: which file is trying to use ss, char.js or script.js? if it is script.js it is above your socket stream script so it hasn't been defined yet

Comment: @apsillers from the developers who made socket.io-stream he says to just write it like that. I assumed ss will be retrieved from socket.io-stream.js import?

Comment: @PatrickEvans script.js

Comment: Move script.js below socket stream script then, as with it above it ss hasnt been defined yet. Scripts are retrieved and executed in order (unless they have async or defer attributes). So if one script needs to use something in another script, that script has to come before it

Comment: @PatrickEvans oh god, such a simple mistake which I've been trying to figure out for past two hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

move socket.io-stream.js to your public/js folder and include this js file in your EJS or any client side view file